# Count / Compare an array with other array and get value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a scenario in which i have multiple Array.

Following is array

```
$main_heading = [Main Heading 1, Main Heading 2, Main Heading 3, Main Heading 4];

    $sub_heading1 = [Sub Heading1]; 

$sub_heading2 = [Sub Heading2, Sub Heading2]; 

$sub_heading3 = [Sub Heading3, Sub Heading3, Sub Heading3];

 $sub_heading4 = [Sub Heading4, Sub Heading4, Sub Heading4, Sub Heading4];
```

I use `implode` with all `$subheading` and now it convert in one array shown following

```
$sub_heading=[Sub Heading1 - Sub Heading2, Sub Heading2 -  Sub Heading3, Sub Heading3, Sub Heading3 - Sub Heading4, Sub Heading4, Sub Heading4, Sub Heading4 ];
```

Now i have two another array

```
$main_headin_score = [good, strong, Adequate, Need Improvements];

$sub_heaing_score = [good, strong, Adequate, Need Improvements, good, strong, Adequate, Need Improvements, good, strong];
```

Following Pic show that how i want to save this data in my [image]

Comment: There's no code sample you had tried, nor question :) . Please provide both

Comment: @Armage I have no idea how i can make a logic for this. That's why i put my question here :)